# std::hash for std::chrono::duration

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, c++-chrono

I'm trying to key a set of objects on a std::chrono::duration.  This will not compile:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>

class Foo final
{
public:

    Foo() {}

    int y;
};


int main(void)
{
    auto map = std::unordered_map<std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>, Foo>();

    map[std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(5)].y = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

> /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of
>   'struct std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash >, std::hash > > >':

I'm guessing the problem here is there's no std::hash implementation for std::chrono::duration?  If not, is there a way of doing this without resorting to keying on the eminently breakable count()?

Comment: `float`s are not hashable, that's the problem.

Comment: Changed to int but still have the same problem, though now the solution is probably more tractable.

Comment: I could just hash on milliseconds and give my class a "this must be in milliseconds" prerequisite but I'd quite like it to work with any duration.

Comment: What's wrong with hashing count()?

Comment: count would return the same value for 10 milliseconds as it does for 10 nanoseconds.  I would have to make using a given unit a prereq of class usage.

Comment: So? Your map key is millisecond duration, as such, all count()s will be milliseconds.

Comment: How big of a duration do you need to support?  If it is not too big the you could use a single fine grained type for the map and then `duration_cast` other durations to that type.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking I'll duration_cast in the class methods, as R2RT suggests, to some base unit.

Comment: @Robinson I had to fix myself, static_cast is enough: "Casting between floating-point durations or between integer durations where the source period is exactly divisible by the target period (e.g. hours to minutes) can be performed implicitly, no duration_cast is needed. " http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast notes

Comment: OK, that's good enough for my purposes I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could hide `count` under your own std::hash implementation http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>

class Foo final
{
public:

    Foo() {}

    int y;
};

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

// custom specialization of std::hash can be injected in namespace std
namespace std
{
    template<typename _rep, typename ratio>
    struct hash<std::chrono::duration<_rep, ratio>>
    {
        typedef std::chrono::duration<_rep, ratio> argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
        {
            return std::hash<_rep>{}(s.count());
        }
    };
}


int main(void)
{
    auto map = std::unordered_map<std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>, Foo>();

    map[std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(5)].y = 12;
    std::cout << map[5ms].y; // thanks to std::chrono_literals

    return 0;
}
```

If you are afraid of passing different ratios into your map you could also use `static_cast` into some minimal time precision, eg. `std::micro`:

```
return std::hash<_rep>{}( static_cast<std::chrono::duration<_rep, std::micro>>(s).count());
```

Comment: @Robinson, I've just edited my answer, static_cast is enough